# Format Filename for Process Core Files per Session

Tags: linux, debugging, multi-core

Is there a way to change the core filename format per session instead of for the entire machine?
On Linux the only way I can find is using sysctl as root:

```
sudo /sbin/sysctl -w "kernel.core_pattern=core-%H-%N-%P"
```

On Solaris same problem with root

```
coreadm -g core-%n-%f-%p
```

But unfortunately both these commands change the system permanently for all users, which I wish to avoid.

What I want is to be able to put a command in my .bashrc and as a non priv user have my core files be placed and named where I want them.

**EDIT:**

Just found out you can do this in solaris with

```
coreadm -p core-%n-%f-%p $$
```

Does anyone know about Linux?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Linux, as far as I can tell, the core file name pattern is a global kernel setting.

The core file name is determined by [`format_corename`](http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v2.6.36/+code=format_corename) in [`fs/exec.c`](http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v2.6.36/fs/exec.c#L1461). It is computed from the [`corename`](http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v2.6.36/+code=corename) variable, which is set only through the `kernel.core_pattern` [sysctl](http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v2.6.36/Documentation/sysctl/kernel.txt#L142).

But maybe the behavior you want can be obtained by setting the core pattern to `|/path/to/foo %h %p`, which causes the core file contents to be piped into the `/path/to/foo` executable. Note that what follows the pipe is [split into words at spaces](http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v2.6.36/lib/argv_split.c#L50).

Comment: Did the `|/path/to/foo %h %p` thing work?